# max of a summation

Tags: notation

I have a nooby question regarding the max of a summation. How does one read the following:

$$ max \sum_{u \in V} log(Pr(N_{s}(u) | f(u))$$

Does the summation not just return a single value? If it does then how are you supposed to take a max from that?

Comment: btw this equation was taken from a paper I was reading (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00653.pdf)

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions like max and log you get the proper font and spacing, so \log x gives $\log x$ in contrast to log x giving $log x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the paper there is a subscript $f$ under the $\max$, so it is finding the function $f$ out of some collection of functions that maximizes the sum.